# Assigning PFUser with A PFObject Swift

Tags: ios, parse-platform, xcode6.3.1

How can I add a PFUser to a PFObject, here is my code now:

```
var gameScore = PFObject(className: "SiteLog-\(jobName.text)")
gameScore["TypeOfWorks"] = "\(typeOfWorks.text)"
gameScore["DateAndTime"] = "\(formattedDate)"
gameScore.saveInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (success: Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if (success) {
            // The object has been saved.
            println("sucessfully sent to parse!")
        } else {
            // There was a problem, check error.description
            println("Error Sending to Parse = \(error)")
        }
```

So how would I be able to assign a user to it, the user is already logged in so how can I assign this PFObject to the current user logged in!

I am using iOS Swift - Xcode 6.3.1

Thanks,
George Barlow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Objective-C you can reference the logged in user by calling `[PFUser currentUser]`, which should translate to Swift as `PFUser.currentUser()`. Say you have a column for gameScore called `user`, you can add this line of code before saving gameScore:

```
    if let user = PFUser.currentUser(), username = user.username {
        user["column-name-in-parse-data"] = username
    }
```

Comment: Yeh but when I do that it prints out alot of like numbers followed by the username but how do I just get the username or is that not possible @Tatonka

Comment: Updated my answer to get you the username.

Comment: Were you able to get it working with the updated answer?

Comment: Not exactly it gives me an error saying 'Cannot scripture a value of type PFUser? with a index of type 'string'' @Tatonka

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot that PFUser has its own methods and fields. Updated the answer again. Let me know if it works.

Comment: You are more than welcome, glad I could help :) Could you please mark my answer as accepted?